# How to initial a cstring in constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, c-strings

My homework requires using cstring to hold full name, so in header file I have

```
private:
char fullName[50];
```

In my cpp file I have two constructor

```
Employee_C::Employee_C(){
fullName = "";}
Employee_C::Employee_C(char name[]){
fullName = name;}
```

But it gives me error line, it says expression must be a modifiable value/

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't assign a value to a c-string (`char[]`) that way. See `strcpy`.

Comment: We don't see _any_ constructor. Please read the chapter about making a [mre].

Comment: Tactical note: You'll have more versatility if you change `Employee_C(char name[])` to `Employee_C(const char name[])`.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text, as character arrays can overrun.

Answer (score 1):

In the both constructors

```
Employee_C::Employee_C(){
fullName = "";}
Employee_C::Employee_C(char name[]){
fullName = name;}
```

the lines

```
fullName = "";
fullName = name;
```

are assignment statements. But arrays do not have the copy assignment operator.

What you need is the following

```
#include <cstring>

//...

Employee_C::Employee_C() : fullName { "" }
{
}
```

and

```
Employee_C::Employee_C( const char name[] )
{
    strncpy( fullName, name, sizeof( fullName ) );
    fullName[sizeof( fullName ) - 1] = '\0';  
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Employee_C
{
public:
    Employee_C();
    Employee_C( const char name[] );
    
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Employee_C &employee )
    {
        return os << employee.fullName;
    }
private:
    char fullName[50];  
};

Employee_C::Employee_C() : fullName { "" }
{
}

Employee_C::Employee_C( const char name[] )
{
    strncpy( fullName, name, sizeof( fullName ) );
    fullName[sizeof( fullName ) - 1] = '\0';  
}

int main() 
{
    Employee_C employee1;
    Employee_C employee2( "Ke Xu" );
    
    std::cout << employee1 << '\n';
    std::cout << employee2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Ke Xu
```

Comment: How is `strncpy(fullName, name, sizeof(fullName));` superior to `strcpy(fullName, name);`?

Comment: @Beta `strncpy()` does bounds checking to ensure the dest `char[]` does not overflow into surrounding memory if the source `char[]` is longer. `strcpy()` does not provide that same safety. On the other hand, `strncpy()` will not null-terminate the dest `char[]` if the source `char[]` is longer, hence the manual assignment of a null terminator afterwards.

Comment: @Beta It prevents undefined behavior.:)

Comment: [facepalm] I got the source and destination mixed up (as I've done about 1/4 of the time I've used str(n)cpy over the last few decades). I thought that statement was measuring the size of the source.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I run into problem with the first constructor, it gives me error that it expect  {} after Employee_C()

Comment: @KeXu See my appended post.